# Can I use Apple artwork in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, icons

In my app, I want to give the user the opportunity to add some comments to a listed item.
Rather than showing a "add comments" button, I want to show a little icon.
Being lazy, but also, using the visual language of a Mac user, I would like to use the the icon of the TextEdit application.
What would Apple think of this?
Obviously, I could design something myself, but that is another topic.

Comment: I'd guess a "ballon" for comments is pretty common, see http://www.jilborn.se/Images/pratbubbla_h.gif

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would absolutely stay away from this.  Since apple runs the approval process for iPhone apps they might reject your app for infringing on what would probably be copyright or trademarked work.

From a visual perspective, I do not think the TextEdit icon would be best for an "add comments" icon.  It seems too general.  I think your best bet would be to design something yourself or find a royalty free image online.

Comment: Hmm. That scares me. There's a lot of 'might' here, but I guess I should overcome my laziness. Thanks.

Comment: You don't want to run the risk - Apple can be a bit.. uh.. "touchy" about some of those gray-areas; and anyway developing your own icon will make your app unique whilst still retaining a familiar Apple style.

Comment: I know of at least one app that has been rejected for using the MobileSafari icon on a button that, when clicked, launched mobile safari. Don't use their art. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Apple rejected an update to my application because [this icon (center)](http://www.marco.org/98224131), drawn by a designer for me and having no copyright whatsoever by Apple, depicts an iPhone.

I wouldn't push your luck. Stay far away from Apple's IP.

Comment: Without the context of your App, I wouldn't understand the icon anyway, but it's really outrageous that Apple is so picky.

Comment: In this case, the icon isn't trademarked, the image it represents is trademarked. Apple has trademarked the "look" of an iPhone, i.e. a rounded rect with top and bottom margins, a screen in the middle and the tell tale "dot" (button) centered in the bottom.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this would be copyright infringement unless you had written permission from Apple. They have a [copyright and trademark policy](http://www.apple.com/legal/trademark/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html) posted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!!!  You CAN  use their icons and they encourage it:

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/system-icons/

> System Icons
>
> iOS **provides lots of small icons**—representing common tasks and types of content—**for use in navigation bars, tab bars, toolbars, and Home screen quick actions. It’s a good idea to use these built-in icons as much as possible because they're familiar to people.**
>
> Provide alternative text labels for icons. Alternative text labels aren’t visible onscreen, but they let VoiceOver audibly describe what's onscreen, making navigation easier for people with visual impairments.

Comment: Your answer is very misleading. Both macOS and iOS come with various icons that you can use in your apps. The post by Apple refers to those icons. App icons however are something entirely different and are most likely copyrighted so you must not use them.